# C# FileInfo move foreach

Tags: c#, foreach, move, fileinfo

I have this code:

```
FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "backup", file.Key)); 
var fsize = finfo.Length;

if (fsize != file.Value)
{
    DialogResult modifiedcleofiles = MessageBox.Show("Oops! Modified files found! Click OK to move them!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning); 
    if(modifiedcleofiles == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        foreach (FileInfo filemove in finfo)
        {
            finfo.MoveTo(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "backup", filemove.Name));
        }
     }
     return;
}
```

But it's error with foreach, how can I fix it?

P.S I'm get this error:

> foreach statement does not work with variables of type System.IO.FileInfo

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear to me. You cannot use a foreach statement with a `FileInfo`. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The foreach needs an enumerable, you're not passing one you're passing a singular instance of FileInfo. What are you trying to do? You seem to mention files but only seem to operate on a single file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to iterate multiple items in a directory, you need a `DirectoryInfo`, not a `FileInfo`, object.

Assuming that you want to get all files in `finfo`'s directory, the code should be like this:

```
foreach (FileInfo filemove in finfo.Directory.EnumerateFiles()) {
    ...
}
```

[`finfo.Directory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.directory(v=vs.110).aspx) gives you `DirectoryInfo` for `finfo`'s directory, and [`EnumerateFiles()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413232(v=vs.110).aspx) lets you go over its content in a `foreach` loop.